# FragmentPagerAdapter dynamic tabs and page count

Tags: java, android, fragmentpageradapter

My application pulls data from a web service that generates different sections for each user. Then I am going to use these sections to create tabs using FragmentPagerAdapter.

I have used an Async task to pull data from the web service. However the overridden methods such as getCount() and getPageTitle() in the  FragmentPagerAdapter executed prior to my asynctask and completes its job. How can I prevent this and generate dynamic number of tabs and their title name based on the data fetched from the web service?

In other words how can I create dynamic number of tabs and titles based on the data fetch from the web service

My Code for FragmentPagerAdapter as below. As you can see I have hard coded the amount of tabs as well as their title names.

```
public class SectionsPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter{

    private boolean proceedStatus = false;
    private String requestURL = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx";

    //list of fragments need to be added dynamically
    public final ArrayList<Fragment> screens = new ArrayList<Fragment>();



    public SectionsPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
        super(fm);

    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        // getItem is called to instantiate the fragment for the given page.
        // Return a DummySectionFragment (defined as a static inner class
        // below) with the page number as its lone argument.
        Fragment fragment = new SectionFragment();
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        args.putInt(SectionFragment.ARG_SECTION_NUMBER, position + 1);
        fragment.setArguments(args);
        return fragment;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return 2;
    }

    @Override
    public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
        Locale l = Locale.getDefault();
        switch (position) {
        case 0:
            return "Camera".toUpperCase(l);
        case 1:
            return getString(R.string.title_section2).toUpperCase(l);
        case 2:
            return getString(R.string.title_section3).toUpperCase(l);
        case 3: 
            return "SECTION 4";
        }
        return null;
    }

    //setting the section title
    private void setSectionTitle(){

    }

    //count the number of sections
    private int countNumberofSections(){
        int numberOfSection = 0;
        return numberOfSection;
    }
}
```

Then I have my Fragment code as below which has the the caller to the Async Task

```
public static class SectionFragment extends Fragment implements OnTaskCompleted {
    /**
     * The fragment argument representing the section number for this
     * fragment.
     */
    private Slider adapter;
    private ViewPager viewPager;
    public static final String ARG_SECTION_NUMBER = "section_number";
    Button thumbUpBut;
    Button thumbDownBut;
    Button captureButton;
    ImageView genImage;
    TextView genCaption;
    private Camera mCamera;
    private CameraPreview mPreview;
    private static File mediaFile;
    private ProgressDialog progress;
    private static String imageSaveLocation;
    private static String file_name_without_extension;
    private ImageView imageView;
    private Button uploadButton;
    private Button cancelButton;
    private Collection<Place> places = null;
    private Collection<Happenings> events = null;
    private Collection<General> general = null;
    private ArrayList<String> sections;

    public int getNumberOfPages(){
        return sections.size();
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main_dummy,container, false);
        TextView dummyTextView = (TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.section_label);
        dummyTextView.setText(Integer.toString(getArguments().getInt(ARG_SECTION_NUMBER)));

        FeedRequest task = new FeedRequest(this);
        task.execute("xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx");  

        captureButton = (Button) rootView.findViewById(R.id.button_capture);
        captureButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                takePhoto();
            }
        });

        thumbUpBut = (Button) rootView.findViewById(R.id.thumbUp);
        thumbUpBut.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(View v) {
                Log.v("thumbPress", "thumbPressUp");
                thumb("up");
            }
        });

        thumbDownBut = (Button) rootView.findViewById(R.id.thumbDown);
        thumbDownBut.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(View v) {
                Log.v("thumbPress", "thumbPressDown");
                thumb("down");
            }
        });

        //allocating the activity one to the camera
        if(getArguments().getInt(ARG_SECTION_NUMBER) == 1){
            mCamera = getCameraInstance();
            mPreview = new CameraPreview(this.getActivity(), mCamera);
            FrameLayout preview = (FrameLayout)rootView.findViewById(R.id.camera_preview);
            preview.addView(mPreview);

            //hide buttons
            thumbDownBut.setVisibility(rootView.INVISIBLE);
            thumbUpBut.setVisibility(rootView.INVISIBLE);
        }else{
            thumbDownBut.setVisibility(rootView.VISIBLE);
            thumbUpBut.setVisibility(rootView.VISIBLE);
            captureButton.setVisibility(rootView.INVISIBLE);
        }

        viewPager = (ViewPager) rootView.findViewById(R.id.pager);
        return rootView;
    }

    //take photo function
    private void takePhoto() {

        //get coordinates of the location
        UserLocation userLocation = new UserLocation();
        userLocation.getUserLocation(getActivity());
        coordinates[0] = userLocation.longitude;
        coordinates[1] = userLocation.latitude;

        PictureCallback pictureCB = new PictureCallback() {
            public void onPictureTaken(byte[] data, Camera cam) {
                new SavePhotoAndMetadata().execute(data);
                cam.startPreview();
            }
        };
        mCamera.takePicture(null, null, pictureCB);
    }

    //get camera instance
    private Camera getCameraInstance() {
        Camera camera = null;
        try {
            camera = Camera.open();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // cannot get camera or does not exist
        }
        return camera;
    }

    //get the media out
    private static File getOutputMediaFile() {
        File mediaStorageDir = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/Android/data/asia.ceynet.realsnap/temp_img");
        if (!mediaStorageDir.exists()) {
            if (!mediaStorageDir.mkdirs()) {
                Log.d("MyCameraApp", "failed to create directory");
                return null;
            }
        }
        // Create a media file name
        String timeStamp = (DateFormat.format("dd-MM-yyyy hh:mm:ss", new java.util.Date()).toString());
        mediaFile = new File(mediaStorageDir.getPath() + File.separator + "IMG_" + timeStamp + ".jpg");
        file_name_without_extension = "IMG_" + timeStamp;
        imageSaveLocation = mediaFile.toString();
        return mediaFile;
    }

    //saving the image and metadata together
    class SavePhotoAndMetadata extends AsyncTask<byte[], String, String> {
        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(byte[]... data) {
            File picFile = getOutputMediaFile();
            if (picFile == null) {
                return null;
            }

            byte[] photoData = data[0];
            try {
                //save the image
                FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(picFile);
                fos.write(photoData);
                fos.close();
            } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                e.getStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.getStackTrace();
            }
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
            progress = new ProgressDialog(getActivity());
            progress.setMessage("Saving Picture..Please wait...");
            progress.show();
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String s) {
            progress.dismiss();
            imagePreviewDialog();
        }
    }

    //save image metadata in async task 
    class SaveMetadataTask extends AsyncTask<Void, String, Void> {

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
            serializeDeserialize.serializeData("This is for testing", file_name_without_extension, Double.toString(coordinates[0]), Double.toString(coordinates[1]), deviceId, deviceEmail);
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Void v) {

        }
    }

    //image preview dialog and its functionality
    private void imagePreviewDialog(){
        //setting the bitmap
        Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(mediaFile.toString());

        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());
        builder.setTitle("Image Preview");
        builder.setCancelable(false);
        LayoutInflater inflater = getActivity().getLayoutInflater();
        ViewGroup vg = (ViewGroup)inflater.inflate(R.layout.sanp_preview_layout, null);
        ImageView image = (ImageView) vg.findViewById(R.id.imageView);
        image.setImageBitmap(rotateBitmap(bmp));
        builder.setView(vg);

         //buttons
         builder.setPositiveButton("Upload",new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) {

                    if(checkInternetConnection.haveNetworkConnection(sContext)){
                        //upload the image
                        uploadImage();

                        //save image metadata
                        new SaveMetadataTask().execute();
                    }else{
                        Toast.makeText(sContext, "Error! No internet connection detected. Image will be uploaded on an active internet connection", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        new SaveMetadataTask().execute();
                    }
                }
         });

         builder.setNegativeButton("Discard",new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) {
                    discardImage(mediaFile.toString());
                    dialog.dismiss();
                }
         });
        builder.show();
    }

    private Bitmap rotateBitmap(Bitmap image){
        int width=image.getHeight();
        int height=image.getWidth();

        Bitmap srcBitmap=Bitmap.createBitmap(width, height, image.getConfig());

        for (int y=width-1;y>=0;y--)
            for(int x=0;x<height;x++)
                srcBitmap.setPixel(width-y-1, x,image.getPixel(x, y));
        return srcBitmap;

    }

    //device email
    private String getDeviceEmail(){
        AccountManager accountManager = AccountManager.get(sContext);
        Account[] account = accountManager.getAccountsByType("com.google");

        //device email
        for(Account accLoop : account){
            deviceEmail = accLoop.name;
        }
        return deviceEmail;
    }

    //upload image to the server
    private void uploadImage(){

        //save metadata

        //call upload service
        Intent intent = new Intent(sContext, HttpUploader.class);
        Bundle loc = new Bundle();
        loc.putDoubleArray("ss", coordinates);
        intent.putExtra("url", PHOTO_UPLOAD);
        intent.putExtra("paths", mediaFile.toString());
        intent.putExtra("deviceid", deviceId);
        intent.putExtra("deviceemail", getDeviceEmail());
        intent.putExtra("posttext", "This is for testing");
        intent.putExtra("filename", file_name_without_extension);
        intent.putExtra("geo", loc);
        sContext.startService(intent);

        Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Your image is being uploaded", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }

    //discard image when the discard button is pressed
    private void discardImage(String imagePath){
        File file = new File(imagePath);
        try{
            file.delete();
        }catch(Exception e){
            Log.e("IMAGE_DELETION_ERROR", e.toString());
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onTaskCompleted(boolean status, String message) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        Log.e("onTaskCompleted", "success" + status);

        if (message == "tumb UP success") {
            thumbUpBut.setSelected(true);
            thumbDownBut.setSelected(false);
            Log.e("tumb", "tumb");

        } else if (message == "tumb DOWN success") {
            thumbDownBut.setSelected(true);
            thumbUpBut.setSelected(false);
            Log.e("tumb", "tumb");
        }
    }

    //listener for fetching main objects
    @Override
    public void onFeedCompleted(ArrayList<Posts> postArray, Multimap<String, Object> multiMap) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        numberOfPages = postArray.size();
        adapter = new Slider(getActivity(), postArray, getContext());
        viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);
        // displaying selected image first
        viewPager.setCurrentItem(postArray.size());

        //saving the keyset
        Set<String> keys = multiMap.keySet();
        sections =  new ArrayList<String>();

        //sorting the categories and creating the category list
        for(String key:keys){

            //getting category list
            if(!sections.contains(keys)){
                sections.add(key);
            }

            //sorting categories
            if(key.equals("Place")){
                places.add((Place) multiMap.get(key));
            }else if(key.equals("Events")){
                events.add((Happenings) multiMap.get(key));
            }else if(key.equals("General")){
                general.add((General) multiMap.get(key));
            }
        }
    }

    //adding the pages to the adaptor dynamically
    public void addPagesDynamically(){

    }
}

//create the parent directory
private void createParentDiectory(){
    File dir = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/Android/data/asia.ceynet.realsnap");
    if(!(dir.exists() && dir.isDirectory())) {
        dir.mkdirs();
    }
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle presses on the action bar items
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
    case R.id.action_post:
        openPost();
        return true;
    case R.id.action_settings:
        // openSettings();
        return true;
    default:
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}

public void openPost() {
    /*
    Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), PhotoActivity.class);
    startActivity(i);
    */
}

public static void thumb(String type) {
    SectionFragment d = new SectionFragment();
    PostThumb task = new PostThumb(type, d);
    task.execute("xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx");
}

//broadcast receiver for picture upload
public class MyWebRequestReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

    public static final String PROCESS_RESPONSE = "asia.ceynet.intent.action.PROCESS_RESPONSE";
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        //String responseString = intent.getStringExtra(HttpUploader.RESPONSE_STRING);
        String reponseMessage = intent.getStringExtra(HttpUploader.RESPONSE_MESSAGE);
        String responseStatus = intent.getStringExtra(HttpUploader.RESPONSE_STATUS);
        String file_to_be_deleted = intent.getStringExtra(HttpUploader.FILE_NAME_WITHOUT_EXTENSION);
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), reponseMessage + " - " + file_to_be_deleted + ".jpg", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        //if uploaded successfully delete or image and metadata
        if(responseStatus.equals("true")){
            File temp_image_dir = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/Android/data/asia.ceynet.realsnap/temp_img/" + file_to_be_deleted + ".jpg");
            File metadata_file = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/Android/data/asia.ceynet.realsnap/temp_img/" + file_to_be_deleted + ".ser");
            try{
                temp_image_dir.delete();
                metadata_file.delete();
            }catch(Exception e){
                Log.e("IMAGE_DELETION_ERROR", e.toString());
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

When you finnish pulling the async data, provide the adapter with the new data and call .notifyDataSetChanged() on that adapter instance and the framework will update the pages and count by itself.

If you wish a more detailed explanation post your FragmentPagerAdapter implementation.

Comment: Could you explain a bit more. From what I can see you now have 2 Fragments which are the same. You process data in the fragment and when the processed data updates, you want to add additional (same ?) fragments to the view pager? Basically you need a data structure in the pager adapter (like screens list variable) and return the appropriate size dynamically in the getCount() method. Hope this makes some sense.

Comment: Before I load the fragments I want to execute the "OnTaskCompleted" (that are implemented in the SectionFragment) interface methods including "onFeedCompleted" and "onTaskCompleted". Then based on the data, I want to generate the fragments

Answer (score 1):

First of all, let me apologize if I'm not making myself clear enough because this is one of my first participation(s) here. But I'll be always here to answer queries related to this answer and clear any confusions arose by my statements.

Since you're using fragments, so I'm assuming you must have included your fragments inside an activity (lets say `MainActivity.java`). 
What you need, can be done inside that activity containing fragment.
Here is the example code of `onCreate` method inside the `MainActivity`

```
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();

    //Instance of viewpager included inside activity_main.xml
    viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.vpMain);


    SectionsPagerAdapter adapter = new SectionsPagerAdapter (fragmentManager);

    //Adding some fragments right from the beginning, you could ignore it if not needed.
    addFragments();

    //This `OnPageChangeListener` will do the trick for you.
    viewPager.addOnPageChangeListener(new ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onPageScrolled(int position, float positionOffset, int positionOffsetPixels) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onPageSelected(int position) {
            //Show the title of fragment
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, adapter.screens.get(position), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            //If fragment being loaded is later than the first one,
            // then add one more fragment after the last fragment to the adapter.
            // integer currentPosition is declared as a field, outside onCreate method and initially set to 0.
            if(position>currentPosition){
                currentPosition+=1;
                adapter.addFragment(new SectionFragment(), "Fragment"+String.valueOf(position+3));
                adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            }else{
                currentPosition--;
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int state) {

        }
    });


} // onCreate ends here.
```

Create this method inside your `MainActivity` (just to add 3 fragments to give your application a head-start.

```
private void addFragments(){
    adapter.addFragment(new SectionFragment());
    adapter.addFragment(new SectionFragment());
    adapter.addFragment(new SectionFragment());
}
```

Then modify your `SectionsPagerAdapter`'s `getItem` and `getCount` methods as below:

```
public class SectionsPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter{

private boolean proceedStatus = false;
private String requestURL = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx";

//list of fragments need to be added dynamically
public final ArrayList<Fragment> screens = new ArrayList<Fragment>();



public SectionsPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
    super(fm);

}

@Override
public Fragment getItem(int position) {
    return screens.get(position);
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return screens.size();
}

//This method will dynamically add a fragment each time it is called.
public void addFragment(Fragment fragment) {
    screens.add(fragment);
}
```

Now, no work related to "adding new fragment to the list" needs to be done inside your `SectionFragment` class.